# Can't run monkeyrunner recorder

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

I'm trying to use `monkeyrunner` for my project. As I understood there are **2 basic scripts** for that:

`monkey_recorder.py:` https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/ics-mr0/monkeyrunner/scripts/monkey_recorder.py

`monkey_playback.py:` https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/ics-mr0/monkeyrunner/scripts/monkey_playback.py

So, `monkey_recorder.py` is for **recording actions**, and `monkey_playback.py` is for **reproducing these actions**.

I found [here](http://hariniachala.blogspot.ru/2011/09/android-application-ui-testing-with.html), that I can **run recorder** with this line:

```
./monkeyrunner monkey_recorder.py
```

I tried to execute this command from this directory:

```
/Users/user/programs/android-sdk-macosx/tools
```

And I got this error:

```
iMac-Developer-2:tools user$ ./monkeyrunner monkey_recorder.py
Can't open specified script file
Usage: monkeyrunner [options] SCRIPT_FILE

    -s      MonkeyServer IP Address.
    -p      MonkeyServer TCP Port.
    -v      MonkeyServer Logging level (ALL, FINEST, FINER, FINE, CONFIG, INFO, WARNING, SEVERE, OFF)
```

So, I expected, that this window will be opened:

[image]

OS: **OS X** Yosemite, *v10.10.5*

Please, help me to solve this problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) a try. It provides similar functionality with the big advantage of being able to generate plain python unit tests or scripts.

[Culebra UI](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/Culebra-GUI) describes the UI similar to `monkey_recorder.py`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to provide the absolute path to your python script if that doesn't work verify if it's an executable or not.

if it's not executable you can provide the execution permession with chmod

```
chmod +x filename.py
```